# SQL query to order by day, date and lead count

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, count

Trying to figure out how to pull data arranged by day, date and leads stats in the following format

Example output format

```
Day                 Date            Leads   

Today               2020/09/14      3
Yesterday           2020/09/13      64
Saturday            2020/09/12      18
Friday              2020/09/11      29
Thursday            2020/09/10      17
Wednesday           2020/09/09      94
```

A lead will is either a email or number

What SQL query can I use to get this

Example data

```
CREATE TABLE weektest(
        date datetime,
        lead VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO weektest(date, lead)
VALUES
(
'2020/09/04 10:36:51', 'number'
);

INSERT INTO weektest(date, lead)
VALUES
(
'2020/09/08 00:47:52', 'email'
);

INSERT INTO weektest(date, lead)
VALUES
(
'2020/09/11 03:03:41', ''
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select dayname(w.date) day, date(w.date) as date, count(*) cnt
from weektest w
group by date(w.date)
order by date(w.date)
```

I am not sure what you want to count: the above query gives you the number of rows per day. If you want the count of distinct lead values, then use `count(distinct leads)` instead of `count(*)`.